# Mess with handlers using .clone() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm trying clone a HTML section with `.clone()` function of jQuery. Everything is OK, but when you interact with the controls, they become a mess with the events and the control with which I did not perform the interaction stops working.

This is the part of my code that clone the HTML:

**UPDATED CODE**

```
var tempForm = $('#onlineVerificationForm');
/* 1 = CP | 2 = FO | 3 = CP and FO */
switch (supervisedCrew) {
    case 1: tempForm.prop('id', 'onlineVerificationForm_CP'); break;
    case 2: tempForm.prop('id', 'onlineVerificationForm_FO'); break;
    case 3:
        var clonedForm = tempForm.clone(true, true);

        clonedForm.prop('id', 'onlineVerificationForm_CP');

        clonedForm.appendTo($('#onlineVerificationReport'));

        tempForm.prop('id', 'onlineVerificationForm_FO');

        $("#headerCPFO").css('display', 'flex');
        $("#onlineVerificationReport").css('padding-top', '50px');
        //$('#btnOnlineFormCP').addClass('ui-state-persist');
        break;
}
```

Case 1 and 2 are single reports, but in the case 3, I need copy first report and clone it in order to have two reports; as you can see, I change the ID in both reports, and same for all controls in each one (in other function) and add a header in order to change the form.

Comment: In case 3, you're updating the id of `$('#onlineVerificationForm')` twice instead of updating the id of the clone, `tempForm`.

Comment: It's also a good idea in terms of performance and clear code to save jQuery collections that you frequently use into variables instead of selecting the element multiple times.

Comment: Create a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: hi @Connum I'm updating the id just just once. I clone first `$('#onlineVerificationForm')` and change the id of the cloned element directly of the DOM object to `'onlineVerificationForm_CP'`, finally, when append the cloned element `$('#onlineVerificationForm')` into the father div that contains all reports, I update its id to `'onlineVerificationForm_FO'`.

Comment: No, you are not necessarily changing the id of the cloned element. To do so, you would use `tempForm.prop(...`. As you have two elements with the same ID after cloning, it's not clear which element(s) `$('#onlineVerificationForm')` will contain and it probably depends on the client how that's handled.

Comment: I've updated the example code and verified that the report ID and his children has been renamed too, but still have the same problem. Any way for bind/unbind at the same time all handlers according to visible report?